# Find element's attribute value

Tags: jquery

I have got the following code :

```
  <ul>
    <li class="jstree-leaf" kids="0" range="5-7" name="mars" public_id="mars_05" ra_depth="5">
        <a href="#"><ins class="jstree-icon">&nbsp;</ins>mars</a>
    </li>
    <li class="jstree-leaf" kids="0" range="8-10" name="pluto" public_id="pluto_8" ra_depth="5">
        <a href="#"><ins class="jstree-icon">&nbsp;</ins>pluto</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

I need to get the `ra_depth` attribute value of a particular `<li>` by using it's `name` attribute value.

I tried the code below but it's not working:

```
alert(li[name='"+myarray[0]+"'].attr("ra_depth"));
```

`myarray[0]` contains the value "pluto".

Is there anything I am missing?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### Description

You forget `$(` in your selector. Check out my sample and this [jsFiddle Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/Fxst5/)

#### Sample

```
 alert($("li[name='"+myarray[0]+"']").attr("ra_depth"));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
alert($('li[name="'+myarray[0]+'"]').attr("ra_depth"));
```

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the actually jQuery function around your selector:

```
alert($("li[name='"+myarray[0]+"']").attr("ra_depth"));
```

Answer (score 0):

you missed the element seletor here.Try this

> alert($("li[name='"+myarray[0]+"']").attr("ra_depth"));