# VBA/DOM - Get elements based on attribute

Tags: vba, excel, dom

Excel 2013 on Windows 7. `XPath`/`Javascript`/`jQuery` is out of scope.

I am trying to iterate over select `div` elements in a page, namely elements that have a specific `data-level` attribute.

My current approach is [similar to this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20142333/4604845), but I was unable to find a non-manual way to select elements based on attributes. The closest I came was something like:

```
With CreateObject("WINHTTP.WinHTTPRequest.5.1")
    .Open "GET", url, False
    .Send
    pHTML.body.innerHTML = .ResponseText
End With

Set eCollection = pHTML.getElementsByClassName("chapter").getElementsByTagName("div")

For i = 0 To eCollection.Length
    If eCollection(i).getAttribute("data-level") >= 0 Then ' Throw cake
Next i
```

This solution, while I am sure it is viable (if unelegant), seems sub-optimal if only for how big the loop is going to end up being when I start looking for specific elements and sequences of elements within *these elements*.

So I am looking for a way to do something like this:

```
For Each pElement In pHTML.getElementsByClassName("chapter").getElementsByTagName("div").getElementsByAttribute("data-level")
    ' Throw cake at the element
Next
```

**I'm aware that there is no method `getElementsByAttribute`, hence the question.

Is there some approach here that I am blind to, or am I locked to manual iteration?**

Alternatively, if I swap my current approach for creating an IE instance, á la [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31313816/4604845), could I concievably use `querySelectorAll` to end up with something resembling the result I have outlined above?

Comment: querySelectorAll should work, alternatively you can consider using ExecScript and using a jquery statement. Something like this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9032618/find-elements-attribute-value. I find using jquery a clean way of doing this when I need to locate a tricky element.

Comment: I don't code much of JS/jQuery, but I guess I'll have to learn if I can't make `querySelector` work. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For anyone else coming this way, the outer shell, so to speak, can look like this:

```
Sub ScrapeWithHTMLObj(url As String, domClassName As String, domTag As String, domAttribute As String, domAttributeValue As String)
    ' Dependencies:
    ' * Microsoft HTML Object Library

    ' Declare vars
    Dim pHTML As HTMLDocument
    Dim pElements As Object, pElement As Object

    Set pHTML = New HTMLDocument

    ' Basic URL healthcheck
    Do While (url = "" Or (Left(url, 7) <> "http://" And Left(url, 8) <> "https://"))
        MsgBox ("Invalid URL!")
        url = InputBox("Enter new URL: (0 to terminate)")
        If url = "0" Then Exit Sub
    Loop

    ' Fetch page at URL
    With CreateObject("WINHTTP.WinHTTPRequest.5.1")
        .Open "GET", url, False
        .Send
        pHTML.body.innerHTML = .ResponseText
    End With

    ' Declare page elements
    Set pElements = pHTML.getElementsByClassName(domClassName)
    Set pElement = pElements(0).getElementsByTagName(domTag)

    ' Extract only elements with wanted attribute
    pEleArray = getElementsByAttribute(pElement, domAttribute, domAttributeValue)

    For Each e In pEleArray
        ' Do stuff to elements
        Debug.Print e.getAttribute(domAttribute)
    Next
End Sub
```

If you go this route, you'll also need something like this:

```
Function getElementsByAttribute(pObj As Object, domAttribute As String, domAttributeValue As String) As Object()
    Dim oTemp() As Object
    ReDim oTemp(1 To 1)

    For i = 0 To pObj.Length - 1
        'Debug.Print pObj(i).getAttribute(domAttribute)
        If pObj(i).getAttribute(domAttribute) = domAttributeValue Then
            Set oTemp(UBound(oTemp)) = pObj(i)
            ReDim Preserve oTemp(1 To UBound(oTemp) + 1)
        End If
    Next i

    ReDim Preserve oTemp(1 To UBound(oTemp) - 1)

    getElementsByAttribute = oTemp
End Function
```

Depending on the HTML tree, you'll need to change which elements you zero in on in the sub, obviously. For the site I used in testing, this structure worked flawlessly.

Example usage:
`Call ScrapeWithHTMLObj("https://somesite", "chapter-index", "div", "data-level", "1")`

It will enter the first class named `chapter-index`, select all elements with the `div` tag, and finally extract all elements containing the attribute `data-level` with value `1`.

Comment: for those of you who get the wrong value from `getAttribute`, try calling the method as follows: `pObj(i).getAttribute(domAttribute,2)` the extra parameter `2` tells the method to return the value as string and in some cases fixes wrong return value issue.